# jQuery Select from provided HTML?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am implicitly creating some HTML on the fly, to be injected into the DOM.

However, the block of HTML I have to be injected, I need to use jQuery to select an element and do something with it.

I know `$("#element")` selects from the active DOM, but is there anyway to provide jQuery a chunk of HTML as a string and have it select from that instead?

Like for example, heres some pseudo code

```
var html = '<div><span id="selectMe"></span></div>';
// below obviously doesn't work as it'd select from the active DOM
var html = $("#selectMe").html("injected");
```

Is there a way to get jQuery to not select from the DOM but from a variable containing HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
var html = '<div><span id="selectMe"></span></div>';
var $html = $(html);
$html.find('#selectMe').html("injected");
```

*Note: The string `html` will not get updated with the new markup, but the dom structure holded by `$html` will contain the update*

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var html = '<div><span id="selectMe"></span></div>';
var html_var = $(html);
html_var.children('#selectMe').html("injected");
```

Reference

[.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)